# Divs from bootstrap are not created inline

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make div append some other divs that their class is "card" from bootstrap, and make them beeing created in a line but when they're beeing created they show themselfs one under the other.

I tried to edit "card" class by giving it `display: inline-block`
but it does not work.

jQuery:

```
let newCard = document.createElement("div"); 
newCard.className = "card";
$( ".cardsContain" ).append(newCard);
```

CSS:

```
.cardsContain{
        width: 79%;
        margin-left: 9%;
        height: 100%;     
      }
      .card{
        display: inline-block;
         background-image: url('img/facebook.png');
         background-size: 100%;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
      }
```

"cardsContain" is the div that appends each card.

How do I make them showed in the same line?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="test"> 1</div>
<button id="fooBtn">Click me</button>
```

jQuery:

```
  var fooBtn = $('#fooBtn');

  fooBtn.on('click', function() {
      let d = document.createElement("div"); 
      $(d).addClass('card')
          .html('hello, world!')
          .appendTo($("#myDiv"));        
  });
```

CSS:

```
.card{
    display: inline-block;       
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo I created for you. A new card will be added next to each other every time the 'Add Card' Button is pressed.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addCard();">Add Card</button>
<div class="cardsContain row">
```

Javascript:

```
    var i = 0;
    function addCard(){
        i++;
        let column = document.createElement("div");
        column.className = "col-3 column" + i;
        $( ".cardsContain" ).append(column);

        let newCard = document.createElement("div"); 
        newCard.className = "card";
        newCard.innerHTML = '<div class="card-body">' + '<h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>' + '<p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the cards content.</p>' + '</div>';
        $( ".column" + i ).append(newCard);
     }
```